# Iterate over _InternalLinkedHashMap not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to iterate over the following data structure: `{String: [{String, List<SomethingResponse>}]}` where `SomethingResponse = {String: dynamic})`. I created this model:

```
class SomethingsResponse {
  final Map<String, List<SomethingResponse>> SomethingsResponse;
  SomethingsResponse({this.SomethingsResponse});

  factory SomethingsResponse.fromJson(data) {
    return SomethingsResponse(SomethingsResponse: data.map<String, List<SomethingResponse>>((String key, dynamic value) {
      final dataFromCategory = List<SomethingResponse>.from(value.map((x) => SomethingResponse.fromJson(x)));
      return MapEntry(key, dataFromCategory);
    }));
  }
}
```

When I try getting the keys like this: `data.somethingsResponse.toList()`, I get an error saying:

> Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List>' has no instance method 'toList'.

I can't iterate over it or really get any kind of data out of it. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? I have a feeling the issue is at this line `return MapEntry(key, dataFromCategory);`, but I tried creating a `Map` a couple of different ways, and none worked.

Comment: If you want a list of a `Map`'s keys, use [`Map.keys`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-core/Map/keys.html) (e.g. `data.somethingsResponse.keys.toList()`).

Comment: @jamesdlin That worked! Can u post as answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consult the documentation for [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map-class.html), you will see that it does *not* derive from `Iterable` and therefore cannot be directly iterated over.  I presume that this is because it's not obvious *what* you want to iterate over: keys, values, or key-value pairs?

If you want to iterate over keys, use [`Map.keys`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/keys.html). (In your case: `data.somethingsResponse.keys.toList()`)

If you want to iterate over values, use [`Map.values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/values.html).

If you want to iterate over key-value pairs (i.e. `MapEntry` objects), use [`Map.entries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/entries.html).